# Re-write a query to avoid PG::GroupingError: ERROR: in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I tried many alternatives before posting this question.
I have a query on a table A with columns: id, num, user_id.
id is PK, user_id can be duplicate. 
I need to have all the rows such that only unique user_id has chosen to have highest num value. For this, I came up with aSQL below, which will work in Oracle database. I am on ruby on rails platform with Postgres Database.

```
select stats.* from stats as A 
where A.num > (
      select B.num
      from stats as B
      where A.user_id == B.user_id 
      group by B.user_id  
      having B.num> min(B.num) )
```

I tried writing this query via active record method but still ran into

> PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "b.num" must appear in the GROUP BY
>   clause or be used in an aggregate function

```
Stat.where("stats.num > ( select B.nums from stats as B  where stats.user_id = B.user_id group by B.user_id having B.num < max(B.num) )")
```

Can someone tell me alternative way of writing this query

Answer (score 0):

The `SELECT` clause of your subquery in Rails doesn't match that of your example. Note that since you're performing an aggregate function `min(B.num)` in your `HAVING` clause, you'll have to also include it in your `SELECT` clause:

```
Stat.where("stats.num > ( select B.num from stats as B where stats.user_id = B.user_id group by B.user_id having B.num < max(B.num) )")
```

You may also need a condition to handle the case where `select B.num from stats as B where stats.user_id = B.user_id group by B.user_id having B.num < max(B.num)` returns more than one row.

Comment: thanx for pointing B.num thins in the select clause. I made the change and tested it , still getting  ERROR:  column "b.num" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function. Let me think how to handle multiple row case.